# What is the cause of the error "input image must be of non-zero size"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, conv-neural-network, size

Recently, I began studying convolutional neural networks for medical segmented images. I built a simple model. Everything seems to work, but at the stage model.fit gives an error.

> input image must be of non-zero size [[node
> model/up_sampling2d/resize/ResizeNearestNeighbor (defined at :1) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_2038]

I have no idea about the reason why it doesn't work, but I think that something is wrong with either loading data or creating arrays. I attach the code with the explanation. I perform in colab.

Importing required libraries

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

from glob import glob
import skimage.io as io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

path = '/content'
end = '/Study-DCM/*.dcm'
```

Downloading files

```
files = glob(path+end, recursive=True)

files
```

Setting simpleitk for read images

```
!pip install simpleitk
```

Create a function to convert regular images to an array

```
def to_array(path, end):
  files = glob(path+end, recursive=True)
  img_list = []

  for file in files:
    img = io.imread(file, plugin="simpleitk")
    img = ((img - img.min())/(img.max() - img.min()))
    img.astype("float32")

    for slice in range(2, 33):
      img_s = img[slice,:,:]
      img_s = np.expand_dims(img_s, axis=-1)
      img_list.append(img_s)

  return np.array(img_list,np.float32)
```

Create a function to convert segmented images to an array

```
def seg_to_array(path, end):
  files = glob(path+end, recursive=True)
  img_list = []

  for file in files:
    img = io.imread(file, plugin='simpleitk')
    
    img.astype("float32")

    for slice in range(2,33):
      img_s = img[slice,:,:]
      img_s = np.expand_dims(img_s, axis=-1)
      img_list.append(img_s)
  
  return np.array(img_list,np.float32)
```

Create arrays

```
lungs = to_array(path=path, end=end)
seg = seg_to_array(path=path, end='/Masks-DCM/*.dcm')
```

Creating a training set with slices

```
lungs_train = lungs[:1200]
seg_train = seg[:1200]
```

Creating a test set using slices

```
lungs_test = lungs[1200:]
seg_test = seg[1200:]
```

Structure of the neural network

```
def unet_model():
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((512, 512, 1))
  
  # -- Encoder -- #
  # Block encoder 1
  conv1 = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (inputs)
  conv1 = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (conv1)
  
  # Block encoder 2
  pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), data_format='channels_last')(conv1)
  conv2 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (pool1)
  conv2 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (conv2)
  
  # Block encoder 3
  pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), data_format='channels_last')(conv2)
  conv3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (pool2)
  conv3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (conv3)
  # -- Encoder -- #

  pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), data_format='channels_last')(conv3)
  conv4 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
  conv4 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)

  # -- Decoder -- #
  # Block encoder 1
  conv_t_1 = Conv2D(8, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same') (conv4)
  up_s_1= UpSampling2D(size = (2, 2),)(conv_t_1)
  conc1 = concatenate([conv3, up_s_1], axis=-1)
  conv5 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (conc1)
  conv5 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (conv5)

  # Block encoder 2
  conv_t_2 = Conv2D(4, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same') (conv5)
  up_s_2= UpSampling2D(size = (2, 2))(conv_t_2)
  conc2 = concatenate([conv2, up_s_2], axis=-1)
  conv6 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (conc2)
  conv6 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (conv6)

  # Block encoder 3
  conv_t_3 = Conv2D(2, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same') (conv6)
  up_s_3= UpSampling2D(size = (2, 2))(conv_t_3)
  conc3 = concatenate([conv1, up_s_3], axis=-1)
  conv7 = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (conc3)
  conv7 = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (conv7)

  conv_final = Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv7)

  model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv_final])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
  
  return model

model = unet_model()
```

Generation of neural network structure

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

Generation of generators

```
def get_gen(data_x: list, data_y: list):
  assert len(data_x) == len(data_y), "Ошибка не соответствия данных"
  while True:
    for i, el in enumerate(data_x):
      yield data_x[i], data_y[i]

lungs_tr_gen = get_gen(lungs_train, seg_train)
lungs_ts_gen = get_gen(lungs_test, seg_test)
```

And the place where the error occurs

```
model.fit(lungs_tr_gen, epochs=10, validation_data=(lungs_ts_gen))
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error suggest that you have empyt `array` and you could first use `print()` to see what you really have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"`. First I would check `img[slice,:,:]` because it may generate empty array if `img` is smaller then `range(2, 33)`. And `lungs[1200:]` may also generate empty list if `lungs` has less then 1200 elements.